# Storage of the images in Commons 6.25: serious troubles acompanied with CHMOD & CHOWN-issues

Tags: media

Where do the image files reside? I have problems with the files, and the permissions. On my site, which runs Drupal-Commons, I cannot upload any image, either to a user or a group.

I was not able to fix it. First of all, regarding the user, my server works with the SETGID-bit enabled, and with the user vhost:vhost.
The bad is that every time I touch the chmod, I lose the setgit-bit; I tried changing it to 2777, and then all gets lost. I lose the style too.

What can I do? Can I upload the images manually, and store them into /home/vhost/WWW/schulcenter.org/sites/default/files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setuid and setgid are for *execution* and not access control.

I can't comment on your exact problem, but when I move a site, I do

```
sudo find /path/to/site/default/files -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find /path/to/site/default/files -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /path/to/private -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find /path/to/private -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo chown -R apache.apache /path/to/docroot/site/default/files 
sudo chown -R apache.apache /path/to/private
```

By default, files are in `site/default/files` but this location can vary for a few reasons

- Admin setting for public files
- Admin setting for private files
- Whether the files use public or private
- Whether you use the default location, or a site alias

and probably some others I can't think of.  I suspect that your write errors will show up in your Apache `error_log` and you should also see what the status report (`admin/reports/status`) says.

Note that the private paths/settings are for Drupal 7 only, but the rest applies.

Comment: hi MPD many manythanks - great input! BTW - do you do all your CHMOD-Things with Drush or with command-line itself!?

Comment: Via bash itself.  I don't think drush will do this.  I actually have this as part of a deploy script that I use.

Comment: thX for all the hints and advices especially the lines **sudo chown -R /path/to/docroot/site/default/files apache.apache
sudo chown -R /path/to/private apache.apache** are very important.

Comment: Just noticed that I had the args backwards on the chown  lines.